# Bootstrap append a textfield inline with a radio btn

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am looking for a way to append a text field inline with a radio button, I am currently using Boostrap. If someone know a specific class for this purpose, that will be appreciated.

My current approach is always mis-aligned, the textbox goes right under the radio button which is something i dont want.

JSFiddle here. http://jsfiddle.net/fs85eedu/

```
      <div class="radio">
            <label class="control-label">
                <input type="radio" name="radioname" id="radioid" class="radio_class">
                <label>text here</label>
                   <div class='row'>
                     <div class="col-md-5">
                       <input type="text" id="q4_c_1_2" name="q4_c_text" placeholder="Enter role/titile" class="form-control">
                     </div>
                   </div>
                </label>    
        </div>
```

Comment: put it in a jsfiddle with your css

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fs85eedu/ please see it here. Thanks. :)

Comment: Do you mean you want an input group that includes a textbox and a radio button? This specific example is in the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-checkboxes-radios)

Comment: @CarrieKendall I guess what i am talking about is more like.."the other" radio btn. Its very common feature in survey. You have a set of radio button and the very last one is "the other" option and there is a text field which allows user to type in the answer.

Comment: Would the linked example not suffice?

Comment: Here is [a visual example](http://www.bootply.com/18VhdnXCrn). That's all pretty much copy/pasted from documentation as well. I can link to the sections if you'd like.

Comment: @CarrieKendall so to be more clear, i want to put a `<label>`  which contain a text for radio button between the radio button and text field. I way im doing now always make the text field go down to second line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78459/discussion-between-chi-and-carrie-kendall).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this. Just put both controls in same `row`.

```
<div class="radio">
    <div class='row'>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <label class="control-label"></label>
            <input type="radio" name="radioname" id="radioid" class="radio_class">
            <label>text here</label>
        </div>    
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <input type="text" id="q4_c_1_2" name="q4_c_text" placeholder="Enter role/titile" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```